# AWS Encryption SDK for .NET -- Binding AWS-Encryption-SDK to C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, encryption, pinvoke, dllimport

My current project is using the AWS-Encryption-SDK for Python and Node in respective solutions, but we also need a corresponding solution in .NET. However, AWS does not have that SDK in C# yet.

Does anyone out there have experience with binding the AWS-Encryption-SDK in C/C++ to .NET using PInvoke, Marshalling, and/or DllImport attribute usage?

Answer (score -1):

Once you have generated DLL using C/C++ code, ensure the generated DLL is copied alongside other DLL's the project is dependent on.

Add the following code in your C# project which would invoke the Function present in  DLL

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
            
[DllImport("GeneratedDLLName.dll", EntryPoint = "FunctionName")]
public static extern string Foo(string payload);

public string InvokeSDKMethod(string payload)
{
  var response = Foo(payload);
  return response;
}
```